# strcmp and strcmp_sse functions in libc

Tags: intel, glibc, disassembly

I've seen that in libc.so the actual type of strcmp_sse to call is decided by the function strcmp itself.

Here it is the code:

```
      strcmp:
 .text:000000000007B9F0                 cmp     cs:__cpu_features.kind, 0
 .text:000000000007B9F7                 jnz     short loc_7B9FE
 .text:000000000007B9F9                 call    __init_cpu_features
 .text:000000000007B9FE
 .text:000000000007B9FE loc_7B9FE:                              ; CODE XREF: .text:000000000007B9F7j
 .text:000000000007B9FE                 lea     rax, __strcmp_sse2_unaligned
 .text:000000000007BA05                 test    cs:__cpu_features.cpuid._eax, 10h
 .text:000000000007BA0F                 jnz     short locret_7BA2B
 .text:000000000007BA11                 lea     rax, __strcmp_ssse3
 .text:000000000007BA18                 test    cs:__cpu_features.cpuid._ecx, 200h
 .text:000000000007BA22                 jnz     short locret_7BA2B
 .text:000000000007BA24                 lea     rax, __strcmp_sse2
 .text:000000000007BA2B
 .text:000000000007BA2B locret_7BA2B:                           ; CODE XREF: .text:000000000007BA0Fj
 .text:000000000007BA2B                                         ; .text:000000000007BA22j
 .text:000000000007BA2B                 retn
```

What I do not understand is that the address of the strcmp_sse function to call is placed in rax and never actually called. Therefore I am wondering: who is going do call *rax? When?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux dynamic linker supports a special symbol type called [STT_GNU_IFUNC](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/403). Strcmp is likely implemented as an IFUNC. 'Regular' symbols in a dynamic library are nothing more but a mapping from a name to the address. IFUNCs are a bit more complex than that: the address isn't readily available, in order to obtain it the linker must execute a piece of code from the library itself. We are seeing an example of such a peice of code here. Note that in x86_64 ABI a function returns the result in RAX.

This technique is typically used to pick the optimal implementation based on the CPU features. Please note that the selection logic runs only once; all but the first call to strcmp are fast.

Comment: I see. So, tell me if I am wrong. What happens is that: the main  binary calls strcmp for the first time, the execution flow continues in the strcmp entry in the .plt section, then in the .got, finally back in the .plt (since it if the first time the strcmp is called). From here the loader executes the code above to infer which is the most suitable strcmp and stores its address in rax (according x86_64 ABI standard). Up to here everything makes sense to me, I just some doubts on what follows: the loader store the retrieved address in the strmp .got entry and then does call *rax? Is it correct?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to research the actual implementation on your own.